# ArcGIS API for JavaScript map is always 400px by 400px

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dojo, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

In my project, I am using ArcGIS API for JavaScript https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/ but for the (insert really big bad word here) I can't override this stupid width/height. No matter what I do, it just does not change, the map comes out to be 400px by 400px.

I tried to Google it found some CSS examples but none did work.

This is what is going on - initially when map loads the size is 400 x 400 then after window re-size it does occupy the whole screen. I have tried to set size on that div with !important. Still nothing.

Maybe someone did run into the same problem. I need to set that stubborn map to width: 100%; height: 100%

[image: CSS ArcGIS Map]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is related to the bootstrap tab you're placing your map in. When initializing your map, the tab-pane has it's style set to `display: none`; The map doesn't know what to do with that so it falls back to it's default size, 400 by 400. You can initialize the map *after* the tab is visible so map gets the size you've set via CSS:

```
var map;

// Check when tabs get switched
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // Check if is tab with map element
    if (e.target.textContent === 'ArcGIS') {
        // Check if map is not already initialized
        if (map === undefined) {
            // Initialize
            require([
                "esri/map",
                "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function(Map) { 
                map = new Map('map', {
                    center: [4.9, 52.378333],
                    zoom: 11,
                    basemap: 'topo'
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Testcase with problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/rOcpNeRPZau7vJQUSnGB?p=preview

Testcase with solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/Tqo6M3EhyDjrNTrCwM0T?p=preview

Normally it should be possible to call the `resize` method of the map so it reinitializes it's size but one way or another that just won't work in this case.

See: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#resize

Your problem is also described here and there is supposed to be a solution but the esri employee doesn't respond anymore :/

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/94922

Comment: Exactly the issue - the map needs to be initialized after the tab is visible. Solved my problem, +1

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon what @iH8 said, when the map is created, it starts at the map div's node, and works up each parentNode to to calculate the width and height of the map. If any node containing the map does not have a width or height assigned through css, the ArcGIS API for JavaScript overrides the map width and height and sets it to 400px by 400px. If all the widths are set in the HTML DOM tree from HTML to the map's div, but the heights aren't all set, You'll end up with a map with the width you specified, but the height will be 400px.

I'd follow iH8's suggestions on how to solve it, and make sure all widths and heights are assigned, either by px, em, or %.

Answer (score 0):

I just stambled uppon this question having problem because my map was inside an invisible div in kendo-ui window.
So just wanted to add that if the map div changes a good solution is after the resize or open ( any way to get the div visible) is to set the div's height and width

```
        $("#"+config.map).height("100%");
        $("#" + config.map).width("100%");
```

The main problem with the accepted answer is that you create a new variable of map all the time , mostly in a GIS application you will have events bound to that map and it is passed as parameter. So using globals is a horrible way to solve it

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that Element-level styles will always override any other styles, as they are last to resolve. No amount of CSS will override an element-level style. To edit that, you'll have to modify it coming out of the server to show up as the size you want, or use Javascript to modify the element style settings when the window resizes.

Also keep in mind that any parent divs or containers may also need to be resized to take the full effect. It looks like the parent  has a 400x400 limitation as well. You'll need to expand that too more than likely.

Here's a possible Javascript example of resizing the elements to 600x600 when a resize occurs. Not probably what you want, but could give you an idea maybe.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('mapDiv_root').style.width = "600px";
    document.getElementById('mapDiv_root').style.height = "600px";

    document.getElementById('mapDiv').style.width = "600px";
    document.getElementById('mapDiv').style.height = "600px";
};
```